# how to make ui-component onload dependency field in admin

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, dependent-fields

how to make ui-component  onload dependency field in admin

In magento 2, admin ui-component form i created some dependency field on value change handler. its working well but  when edit the form  dependent field are not appear.

> view/adminhtml/web/js/applyoptions.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';
    return select.extend({   
        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {

            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = max_discount');
            var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = priceselector');
            var field3 = uiRegistry.get('index = skip_rule');
            var field5 = uiRegistry.get('index = nqty');
            var field7 = uiRegistry.get('index = apply_discount_to');
            var field9 = uiRegistry.get('index = each_product');
            var field8 = uiRegistry.get('index = use_for');
            var field10 = uiRegistry.get('index = promo_sku_x');
            var field11 = uiRegistry.get('index = promo_sku_y');
            var field12 = uiRegistry.get('index = promo_category');
            var field13 = uiRegistry.get('index = promo_skus');


            if(value == 'thecheapest' || value == 'themostexpencive' || value == 'moneyamount') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.hide();
                field8.hide();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.hide();
            } 
            else if(value == 'buyxgetn_perc') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.show();
                field7.hide(); 
                field8.hide();          
                field9.hide(); 
                field10.show();
                field11.show();
                field12.show();
                field13.hide();
            }           
            else if( value == 'buyxgetn_fixdisc' || value == 'buyxgetn_fixprice') {
                field1.show();
                field2.hide();
                field3.show();
                field5.show();
                field7.hide(); 
                field8.hide();          
                field9.hide(); 
                field10.show();
                field11.show();
                field12.show();
                field13.hide();
            } 
            else if(value == 'eachn_perc' || value == 'eachn_fixdisc' || value == 'eachn_fixprice') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.show();
                field8.show();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.hide();

            }
             else if(value == 'eachmaftn_perc' || value == 'eachmaftn_fixdisc' || value == 'eachmaftn_fixprice') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.show();
                field8.hide();
                field9.show();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.hide();

            }
            else if(value == 'groupn'  ) {
                field1.show();
                field2.hide();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.show();
                field8.hide();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.show();

            }
            else if(value == 'groupn_disc'){
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.show();
                field8.hide();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.show();
            }

            else {
                field1.hide();
                field2.hide();
                field3.hide();
                field5.hide();
                field7.hide();
                field8.hide();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.hide();
           }                  
            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a  solution for when  edit a ui-component form dependent field are  appear.

use a `initialize` function to show a dependent field on load a form

```
initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.onUpdate(this.value());
            return this;
        },
```

> view/adminhtml/web/js/applyoptions.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select, modal) {
    'use strict';
    return select.extend({  
  initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                this.onUpdate(this.value());
                return this;
            }, 
        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {

            var field1 = uiRegistry.get('index = max_discount');
            var field2 = uiRegistry.get('index = priceselector');
            var field3 = uiRegistry.get('index = skip_rule');
            var field5 = uiRegistry.get('index = nqty');
            var field7 = uiRegistry.get('index = apply_discount_to');
            var field9 = uiRegistry.get('index = each_product');
            var field8 = uiRegistry.get('index = use_for');
            var field10 = uiRegistry.get('index = promo_sku_x');
            var field11 = uiRegistry.get('index = promo_sku_y');
            var field12 = uiRegistry.get('index = promo_category');
            var field13 = uiRegistry.get('index = promo_skus');


            if(value == 'thecheapest' || value == 'themostexpencive' || value == 'moneyamount') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.hide();
                field8.hide();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.hide();
            } 
            else if(value == 'buyxgetn_perc') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.show();
                field7.hide(); 
                field8.hide();          
                field9.hide(); 
                field10.show();
                field11.show();
                field12.show();
                field13.hide();
            }           
            else if( value == 'buyxgetn_fixdisc' || value == 'buyxgetn_fixprice') {
                field1.show();
                field2.hide();
                field3.show();
                field5.show();
                field7.hide(); 
                field8.hide();          
                field9.hide(); 
                field10.show();
                field11.show();
                field12.show();
                field13.hide();
            } 
            else if(value == 'eachn_perc' || value == 'eachn_fixdisc' || value == 'eachn_fixprice') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.show();
                field8.show();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.hide();

            }
             else if(value == 'eachmaftn_perc' || value == 'eachmaftn_fixdisc' || value == 'eachmaftn_fixprice') {
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.show();
                field8.hide();
                field9.show();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.hide();

            }
            else if(value == 'groupn'  ) {
                field1.show();
                field2.hide();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.show();
                field8.hide();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.show();

            }
            else if(value == 'groupn_disc'){
                field1.show();
                field2.show();
                field3.show();
                field5.hide();
                field7.show();
                field8.hide();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.show();
            }

            else {
                field1.hide();
                field2.hide();
                field3.hide();
                field5.hide();
                field7.hide();
                field8.hide();
                field9.hide();
                field10.hide();
                field11.hide();
                field12.hide();
                field13.hide();
           }                  
            return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```